# How to loop through all dotnetbar advtreeview?

Tags: c#, treeview, dotnetbar

How can I loop through all of dotnetbar's "AdvTreeView's" children and parents?

Comment: See [How to enumerate through all nodes in AdvTree control](http://www.devcomponents.com/kb2/?p=1357)

Comment: Welcome to SO. **We are here to help in your code.** Please take a [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) of SO and read the [help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help) to see how to ask a question.